# Accessing a value in dynamically named array

Tags: tcl, eval

I need to access a value in array which has been created in a dynamic way - meaning array's name is stored in a variable.
To do this I try to use `eval` command but then get lost with the usage of `$`.
I do succeed to retrieve a key-value pair because no `$` is required in a command like `array get` but what I need to use is `array(key)` pattern.

The expected simplified code would look like:

```
set arr foo;
set val1 v1;
set val2 v2;

eval "array set $arr \{
key1 $val1
key2 $val2
\}";

eval "set x \${$arr(key1)}";
```

As for the last line which is actually the failure, I've tried the following options:

```
eval "set x \${$arr}(key1)";
```

or

```
eval "set x \$$arr(key1)"
```

and even more weird but with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that `$var` is shorthand for `[set var]`. So you could write the command as:

```
set x [set ${arr}(key1)]
```

But for these kind of situations, it's probably easiest to use [`upvar`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/upvar.html):

```
upvar 0 $arr arrvar
set x $arrvar(key1)
```

The `upvar` command creates an alias to a variable in the specified stack frame. By specifying the level as '0', it creates an alias to another variable in the current scope. So this command makes `arrvar` an alias for the variable name stored in the `arr` variable.

Comment: Actually, the array is created in the same scope with the "eval". I am not sure this is a relevant option

Comment: The '0' argument to `upvar` refers to the current scope.

Comment: Wow :)
Both solutions work just fine!
Could you elaborate how did the "upvar 0" option work?

Comment: Well yes, if at all possible I test my code before I post it.
I have added an explanation to my answer.